# access variable of another class

Tags: objective-c, variables, properties, getter-setter

How to access variables of other class? This is how I implemented it.

```
@interface Class1 :NSObject {
NSString *Data;
}
    @property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *Data;
    
    @implementation Class1
    @synthesize Data;
    someMethod{
    self.Data = @"something";
    }
    
and in Class2 :

    @implementation Class2
    someMethodOfClass2{
    Class1 *c=[[Class1 alloc]init];
    [c someMethod];
    NSString *str=c.Data;
}
```

I get c.Data as null in Class2. Am I doing anything wrong here?

-----------myClass1--------------

```
@interface APIManager : NSObject {
    NSString *Data;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *Data;

-(void)getData;

@end

@implementation APIManager

@synthesize Data;

-(void)getData{
self.Data=@"response";
}
```

--------myClass2-------------

```
@interface Search : NSObject {
    
}

-(void)searchForItems:(NSString *)query;

@end

@implementation Search

-(void)searchForItems:(NSString *)query {
APIManager *apiManager=[[APIManager alloc]init];
[apiManager getData];
NSLog(@"%@",[apiManager Data]);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably use `self.Data = @"something"` instead of `self.Data = "something"`

Comment: Sorry I did not write the whole code. Its just an excerpt. self.Data=@"Somethin" is proper and also "Data" is declared in interface.

Comment: You're still missing a couple of pieces (both methods should be marked as such and included in the interface), but apart from that there is no obvious problem with your code. You might want to post a more complete example ;)

Comment: I have added my code. Can you please tell me where i am going wrong.

Comment: Unfortunately I still don't see why it should be null. What does the NSLog print ?

Comment: problem solved. i was doing kind of multi threading. Anyway thanks Thomas

Answer (score 0):

In Objective-C you have to use `@"something"` instead of `"something"`. Also aren't you missing the variable declaration? In your `@interface` you should do something like `NSString *Data`.